# OpenCV: Is it possible to share webcam between processes in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, webcam

This has been asked for windows (the answer is 'splitcam'), but I can't find any resources for doing this on linux.

**Is it possible to share webcam between processes (that use OpenCV) in Linux?**

If there is no existing way to do this, then I am planning a shared-memory camera-server process, that my other processes (up to 5 or so) will connect to. Is attempting zero-copy sharing of the image data a sensible approach?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about others APIs, but Video 4 Linux doesn't support sharing between processes.

Your solution of making a server with shared memory is a good idea. Let me suggest you [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html) for that.